# Aspect Oriented Programming in Ruby

Tags: ruby, frameworks, aop, aspects

What frameworks exist to add AOP to Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't specified any criteria for evaluating different frameworks, so here's one that I found after 3 seconds on Google: **[Aquarium](https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium).**

---

Another one, suggested by [@Telemachus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26702/telemachus): **[gazer](https://github.com/teejayvanslyke/gazer)**.

Comment: Yup, I did about the same: Google suggested [Aquarium](https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium) as you say and also [gazer](https://github.com/teejayvanslyke/gazer).

Comment: Aquarium last had a gem release in October 2009.

Comment: @Andrew the github page that Telemachus linked shows (much) more recent activity, FWIW.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning here, that Aquarium is not thread-safe: https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium/issues/39

Answer (score 13):

With Ruby 2.0+, you don't necessarily need a framework:

```
module BarkLogger
  def bark
    puts "Logging #@name's bark!"
    super
  end
end

class Dog
  prepend BarkLogger

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def bark
    puts "#@name the dog says bark!"
  end
end

Dog.new("Rufus").bark
```

Output:

> Logging Rufus's bark!
>
> Rufus the dog says bark!

Comment: In my opinion this is a great solution. It doesn't require any gems.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug: [aspector](http://github.com/gcao/aspector) could be what you are looking for. It allows you to define aspect and then apply to one or more targets.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 2 or 3 years ago [Aquarium](http://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium) gem at university project. Worked nice, aim of project was comparing with AspectJ, to find out if it is capable of all things as AspectJ. At that time a lot of functionality, which AspectJ was capable of, was missing. But now I see a many things were added, so it's worth a try again.

Answer (score 0):

AspectR (last release looks like in 2002) - originally the canonical AOP library in Ruby.

Facets - has some AOP functionality.